# Matlab GUI pushbutton

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I created a GUI with many pushbuttons. I name a push button "Refresh". What I want to do is when I hit this button, update the variables of the workspace in the central Matlab window by running a m-file that makes all the changes (opens files gets data and puts them in cell arrays and when running again refreshes the data).

I tried everything possible found online like using the name of the m-file under the pushbutton callback function but it doesn't work.

This is the code of my pushbutton function and I added the myparameter.m in it:

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
myparameters
```

But when I run it the variables produced from the m-file are not saved in workspace. If I write myparameters in the main matlab window all the variables created in the m-file are saved in the workspace.

Comment: You provided absolutely NO meaningful information to solve your problem. You need to provide a **simple** example that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Consider using load().

Answer (score 0):

To assign variables in the base workspace from a function, you need to use the `assignin` function; e.g.,

```
assignin('base', 'myVariableName', myVariableValue);
```

Comment: I want everything that i do in the callback function to be assigned in the base workspace. For example I have variables C,D,E,G,H,I and I want them to go to the base workspace. Also the m-file creates 5 excel files with data. Will it keep creating them if nothing goes in the base workspace?

Comment: Well clearly this depends on the code that writes the file, and you still haven't provided a meaningful code sample, so it's impossible to tell.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `myparameters` is a [script](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/scripts-and-functions.html) (it would have to be to work as described), then you should be able to evaluate it in the [base workspace](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/base-and-function-workspaces.html) using [`evalin`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/evalin.html). Here's what your callback will look like:

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
   evalin('base', 'myparameters');
end
```